# How to rerun adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Code

```
    public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{

private List<MessagesHelper> mMessagesHelperList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable;

public MessagesAdapter(List<MessagesHelper> mMessagesHelperList)

{
    this.mMessagesHelperList = mMessagesHelperList;
}



public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView messageText;
    public MessageViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        messageText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);

    }
}
@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_chat,parent,false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    return new MessageViewHolder(V);





}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String current_user_id = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    MessagesHelper messagesHelper = mMessagesHelperList.get(position);
    String from_user = messagesHelper.getFrom();
    final boolean Seen = messagesHelper.isSeen();


    if (from_user != null && from_user.equals(current_user_id)) {
            holder.messageText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.messageText.getLayoutParams();
        params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(params);


        if (Seen==false){
            holder.messageText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }else{
            holder.messageText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

        }



    }else {
            holder.messageText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.messageText.getLayoutParams();
        params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        holder.messageText.setText(messagesHelper.getMessage());
    }

@Override
public  int getItemCount() {
    return mMessagesHelperList.size();
}
```

}

As you can see the background color may change according to data

But in my activity the color doesn't change till i restart my activity... Im guessing its because the color is set when the onCreate of the activity runs..

So i tried something like this

```
    messageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(messagesList);

    messageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    messageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    final Handler handlerr = new Handler();
    int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    final int finalDelay1 = delay;
    handlerr.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handlerr.postDelayed(this, finalDelay1);
        }
    }, delay);
```

But didnt work... how can i reset adapter every second or something o that its up to date? or should i call the oncreate everytime for it to work

Present problem with my code is it works but if the seen = false and then i run activity and then the seen becomes true the color of it remains till i restart activity... So i want it to change without restarting so someone help me out please... Also the data is in firebase so the adapter fetches that data

Custom Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/message_single_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/text_background2"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

not need to set adapter gain and again, simply notify to adapter when the value has been changed.

```
        if(messagesList != null && messagesList.size() > 0){
            mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(messagesList);
            mRListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
```

if mannuly update the adapter

```
        if(messagesList != null && messagesList.size() > 0){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                   messagesList.get(0).Seen = true;
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
          }, 5000);
        }
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appmaster.akash.messageplus/com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)

Comment: Error on the first ;line

Comment: share adapter and xml